# Need a tool to detect memory leaks in C code

Tags: c, debugging, memory-management, memory-leaks

Is there a good application (that has some kind of gui) for testing memory leaks in c code. I would really like to test my assignment/programme but being very new to this, i struggle with using the terminal to do things, especially using gdb for debugging (to me it feels like a blast from the past, where i could be using some visual debugger).

Thanks for the help

edit: platform doesn't matter - i am running everything ;)

Comment: "i am running everything" - WOW, all at once!?  Cool! ;-)

Comment: Well, if you like it or not, I would suggest getting comfortable with the command line. When I started programming, I was an Windows nerd, and a Linux hater, and refused to use it. But I had to, and once I got the basics, I really appreciated using it. Today I only use Windows for gaming ;-).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depending on the platform (you don't mention it) [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is fantastic on Linux systems.  It has no GUI, but doesn't need one.

Just run `valgrind <path to your application + arguments>` and it will run your application and spit out any errors during memory operations.

Add the `--leak-check=full` and `--show-reachable=yes` options after `valgrind` to get stack-traces of where your memory leaks originate.

Comment: "It has no GUI, but doesn't need one" -- I beg to differ, especially since the OP specifically confessed to being uncomfortable with the command line. That said, valgrind's the best tool I know of.

Comment: i can manage the command line if i no what i am typing i suppose, as long as the commands are not to taxing. I struggle with doing lots of terminal stuff, but if its minimal commands and i can just read the output then that should be ok i guess?

Comment: @sbsp: Once you see the kind of detail val-grind produces, you won't mind. :) (It's *awesome*.)

Comment: @ptomato - I've been using Valgrind for about 3 years, and the only two options I know (and need) are those two I gave in my answer.  If the OP has at least managed to use GDB (which by the sound of it, they have) then Valgrind will be a piece of cake.  I actually use Valgrind for debugging some times :)

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, then valgrind can be integrated into the IDE using the Linux Tools module (http://www.eclipse.org/linuxtools/).

Answer (score 2):

[Purify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_Purify) is a great application for this.

Answer (score 1):

There's a gui for analyzing valgrind results: http://alleyoop.sourceforge.net/. Besides, there's (non-free) [purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/) which is great, and i believe there's a trial. It has a GUI.

---

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, [HeapMon](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C2A76F5E-B892-4085-8884-68A7D306AC3F&displaylang=en&displaylang=en) may be of some interest, although it does not explicitly tell you where are your leaks.

Answer (score 0):

valgrind is pretty good on Linux, but it only has a command line interface

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Microsoft's DevStudio then the C run-time library has plenty of memory allocation tracking tools already built-in:

[The Debug Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx)

[_CrtSetDbgFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8h19c37.aspx)

It amazes me how few programmers seem to be aware of these tools!