# How to find if I have a memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I wrote a number crunching algorithm. The idea is that:

1. A small main programs needs very few memory (starts at 2 MB)
2. Then, in a loop, it calls a function that needs quite some memory (around 100 MB) which should be released when the function end. In order to understand what's going on, the function is now always called with the same parameters.

It seems that the program slowly eats memory so I suspect a memory leak. I have tried Address Sanitizer from Clang and Pointer Checker from Intel but they don't find anything.

Now, I am looking at the memory consumption in my Activity Monitor (I am running OSX, but I get the same memory usage from the Unix command "top") and just before the big function is called, the program takes 2 MB. When running the function, the program takes 120 MB. What is strange is that when the program ends up the big function and comes back inside the loop, it now takes 37 MB! Then, when it goes back into the big function, it takes 130 MB. Again, coming back in the loop, it takes 36 MB, then in the big function it takes 140 MB...

So it is slowly drifting away, but not with a regular pattern. How should I trust the memory usage in "top"?

Can memory fragmentation increase the memory usage without memory leak?

---

I let the program run overnight, and here is the data I get:

1. In the first loop, the program takes 150 MB
2. 2 hours later, after 68 loops, the program takes 220 MB
3. After one night and 394 loops, the program takes 480 MB

So it seems that the function that allocates and deallocates memory (about 120 MB) seems to "leak" 1 MB each time it is called.

Comment: How about using RAII?

Comment: have you tried [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: To discover memory leaks is used some tools, as Valgrind. A list of others tools can be see in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476150/need-a-tool-to-detect-memory-leaks-in-c-code.

Comment: Paranaix: All my program runs with RAII but I might have missed some things. I use my own version of std::vector for various reasons but it has always worked fine before. I also call some C library (the MKL) that allocates its own memory, and I release it in the destructor of my class that wraps it. So I do use RAII, but I might have messed up somewhere.

Comment: @InsideLoop  `I use my own version of std::vector for various reasons but it has always worked fine before`  Why?  We have no idea if this home-made vector class of yours is an issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie. For various reasons. One of them is that I use unsigned integers as indices,  another on is that I have a debug mode that initialises all il::Vector<double> to NaN to make debugging easier. It might be an issue, but I've used it for a few months and both Address Sanitizer and Pointer Checker have always be fine with it.

Comment: *"Can memory fragmentation increase the memory usage without memory leak?"*  **Yes**.  More on point, freeing memory doesn't mean that your OS has to immediately purge it from the running process.

Comment: _"For various reasons. One of them is that I use unsigned integers as indices"_ So does `std::vector`. _"I have a debug mode that initialises all il::Vector<double> to NaN"_ Accomplish that by _wrapping_ `std::vector`, not by replacing it entirely.

Comment: @DrewDormann So the number in windows task manager on memory is not reliable at all?

Comment: @Lightness: I want to replace it and I have my reasons (one of them is to work with the same class on all platforms, with the same bounds checking method). Please, this is not the subject of my question.

Comment: @InsideLoop  Something is causing the leaks.  Your home-made vector will always raise suspicion.  What may look good to you could be the reason for the leaks.  For example, we have no idea if you implemented the "rule of 3" correctly for this class.

Comment: @tobi303 it's reliably measuring **something**, but that something is memory the OS has reserved, not memory the program has allocated.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Obviously, nobody can read the entire source code of this class, but I have implemented default constructor, copy/move constructors, copy/move assignment, destructor. Anyway, please this is not the subject of my post. Even if there is a leak here, I want to find where it is. Both Address Sanitizer and Pointer Check do not find anything wrong with those class and the whole program.

Comment: @InsideLoop Your question is "how to find if I have a memory leak".  Sometimes finding a memory leak is done by looking at the code itself.  You don't need a tool for that, just C++ knowledge and experience.

Comment: The subject of your post is "I have a memory leak". We cannot guide you in finding arbitrary memory leaks; well, if we did, it would be a blog post rather than a Q&A. It's better if you produce a _testcase_ so that we can help you find the specific problem in this case, and a home-grown vector replacement is an immediate red flag. As such, it's entirely relevant.

Comment: @Lightness: Thanks for your help, but I am a bit bored with "you should not implement your own version of std::vector" that comes every time I say it. I agree that it is a strong suspect, but I am just tired of answers such as 'just don't do it". I have strong reasons to do so. Mark B answer given below makes a lot of sense and after removing the MKL, it seems that the memory usage goes to an asymptote. So, the MKL seems to be the suspect. Still working on it.

Comment: @InsideLoop: Nobody wrote an answer saying "just don't do it". We're trying to help you to mould this into a constructive and useful question, but you don't seem interested!

Comment: @Lightness: Your first comment was trying to explain me how I should implement my version of std::vector. I don't want to go into all the details, but wrapping a std::vector in my own class does not solve the problem. First, I don't want auto v = il::Vector<double>(n); to touch any of the elements in release mode. The STL forces std::vector<double>(n) to initialize all the elements to 0 which I don't want. I have so many reasons not to use std::vector. I have requested help, and found some. Drew Dormann and Mark B answers turned out to be very useful.

Comment: @InsideLoop: I have not written an answer on this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, make sure that over a long period of time (for example if one iteration takes a minute, run a couple hours) the growth continues. If the growths asyptotes then there's no problem. Next I would try `valgrind`. Then if that doesn't help, you'll have to binary search your code: Comment out bits until the growth stops. I would start by totally removing use of the `MKL` library (leave stubs if you want to) and see what happens. Next, change your vector to `std::vector` just to see if that helps it. After that you'll have to use your judgment.

Comment: Very nice suggestion. I have removed the MKL and it seems that the memory goes to an asymptote. Still working on it...

Comment: The problem might be resolved. Before posting the question, I have solved a bug where "I was writing out of bounds" in a std::unordered_map. After fixing this issue, I thought that the problem was still around as the memory was still slowly growing in the first iterations. As you have suggested, it just seems that memory fragmentation does not make the used memory constant but makes it converge to an asymptote. I ran it for a long period of time and this is what seems to happen now. I'll make it run overnight and see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

I think that I have found the culprit: the MKL (the latest version as of today). I use Pardiso, and the following example leaks very slowly: about 0.1 MB every 13 seconds which leads to 280 MB overnight. These are the numbers I get from my simulation.

If you want to give it a try, you can compile it with:

```
icpc -std=c++11 pardiso-leak.cpp -o main -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -liomp5 -ldl -lpthread -lm
```

Thanks everyone for your help. I have reported the bug to Intel.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "mkl_pardiso.h"
#include "mkl_types.h"

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  const auto n = std::size_t{1000};
  auto m = MKL_INT{n * n};

  auto values = std::vector<double>();
  auto column = std::vector<MKL_INT>();
  auto row = std::vector<MKL_INT>();

  row.push_back(1);
  for(std::size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    column.push_back(j + 1);
    values.push_back(1.0);
    column.push_back(j + n + 1);
    values.push_back(0.1);
    row.push_back(column.size() + 1);
  }
  for(std::size_t i = 1; i < n - 1; ++i) {
    for(std::size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
      column.push_back(n * i + j - n + 1);
      values.push_back(0.1);
      column.push_back(n * i + j + 1);
      values.push_back(1.0);
      column.push_back(n * i + j + n + 1);
      values.push_back(0.1);
      row.push_back(column.size() + 1);
    }
  }
  for(std::size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    column.push_back((n - 1) * n + j - n + 1);
    values.push_back(0.1);
    column.push_back((n - 1) * n + j + 1);
    values.push_back(1.0);
    row.push_back(column.size() + 1);
  }

  auto y = std::vector<double>(m, 1.0);
  auto x = std::vector<double>(m, 0.0);

  auto pardiso_nrhs = MKL_INT{1};
  auto pardiso_max_fact = MKL_INT{1};
  auto pardiso_mnum = MKL_INT{1};
  auto pardiso_mtype = MKL_INT{11};
  auto pardiso_msglvl = MKL_INT{0};
  MKL_INT pardiso_iparm[64];
  for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
    pardiso_iparm[i] = 0;
  }
  pardiso_iparm[0] = 1;
  pardiso_iparm[1] = 2;
  pardiso_iparm[3] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[4] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[5] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[7] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[8] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[9] = 13;
  pardiso_iparm[10] = 1;
  pardiso_iparm[11] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[12] = 1;
  pardiso_iparm[17] = -1;
  pardiso_iparm[18] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[20] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[23] = 1;
  pardiso_iparm[24] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[26] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[27] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[30] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[31] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[32] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[33] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[34] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[59] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[60] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[61] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[62] = 0;
  pardiso_iparm[63] = 0;
  void* pardiso_pt[64];
  for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
    pardiso_pt[i] = nullptr;
  }

  auto error = MKL_INT{0};
  auto phase = MKL_INT{11};
  MKL_INT i_dummy;
  double d_dummy;
  PARDISO(pardiso_pt, &pardiso_max_fact, &pardiso_mnum, &pardiso_mtype,
          &phase, &m, values.data(), row.data(), column.data(), &i_dummy,
          &pardiso_nrhs, pardiso_iparm, &pardiso_msglvl, &d_dummy,
          &d_dummy, &error);
  phase = 22;
  PARDISO(pardiso_pt, &pardiso_max_fact, &pardiso_mnum, &pardiso_mtype,
          &phase, &m, values.data(), row.data(), column.data(), &i_dummy,
          &pardiso_nrhs, pardiso_iparm, &pardiso_msglvl, &d_dummy,
          &d_dummy, &error);
  phase = 33;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
    PARDISO(pardiso_pt, &pardiso_max_fact, &pardiso_mnum, &pardiso_mtype,
            &phase, &m, values.data(), row.data(), column.data(), &i_dummy,
            &pardiso_nrhs, pardiso_iparm, &pardiso_msglvl, y.data(),
            x.data(), &error);
  }
  phase = -1;
  PARDISO(pardiso_pt, &pardiso_max_fact, &pardiso_mnum, &pardiso_mtype,
          &phase, &m, values.data(), row.data(), column.data(), &i_dummy,
          &pardiso_nrhs, pardiso_iparm, &pardiso_msglvl, &d_dummy,
          &d_dummy, &error);

  return 0;
}
```